# How to calculate throughput of particular interface in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, script

Is there any way to calculate throughput per interface (e.g. `eth0`) in Linux system using `ip` command or `ifconfig`?

I tried `bmon`, `nload` - but is it possible to get the same result using some basic Linux command or basic commands in a script?

Comment: Are you sure you have a correct definition for *"bandwidth"*?  I.E. you're expecting to measure a theoretical maximum with a shell command?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246446/throughput-and-bandwidth-difference

Comment: @sawdust Good point. The OP said my answer (which calculates throughput) is "exactly what they were searching for", so I edited the question; it's no longer about bandwidth. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1428484/432690) mentions `/proc/net/dev`. Below is an example script that *roughly* calculates "instantaneous" Bps by reading the file twice, (about) 1 second apart, then subtracting:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

[ "$#" -eq 1 ] || { printf 'usage: %s interface\n' "$0" >&2; exit 1; }

getstats () {
   grep "$1": /proc/net/dev
}

{ getstats "$1"; sleep 1; getstats "$1"; } \
| awk '{rcv=$2-rcv; trnsmt=$10-trnsmt} END {print rcv" "trnsmt}'
```

Example usage (assuming the script is saved as `./showband`):

```
$ ./showband eth0   # the result appears after about 1 second
1272439 535768
$
```

The numbers are `incoming_bytes_per_second outgoing_bytes_per_second`.

Tested on Debian 9.

Comment: Thanks a lot . This is exactly what i am searching for. Tested in CentOS and working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the contents  of `/proc/net/dev`:

- one line per interface
- first line is a header that explains what the columns are

Comment: Thanks, but this result is same as we get in `ip` or `ifconfig` and the size is not real time its just summarizing traffic data.

Comment: @JamesArems: That's how all "real time" meters work anyway: they just summarize how quickly the numbers change per second.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `iftop`?

```
sudo yum install iftop
sudo iftop -i eth0
```